# How to set an umlaut ü in the mail subject

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, diacritics, subject

I need to generate German e-mails which contain umlaut characters. In the e-mail itself this works perfectly, but not in the subject of the e-mail. I've tried many different umlaut letters and they all seem to work except for the ü. I also tried different mail libraries (HTMLMimeMail & PHPMailer) and they both fail at this:

```
$mail = new htmlMimeMail();
$mail->setTextEncoding("base64");
$mail->setHTMLEncoding("base64");
$mail->setTextCharset("UTF-8");
$mail->setHTMLCharset("UTF-8");
$mail->setHeadCharset("UTF-8");
$mail->setSMTPParams(mailinglist_smtp_host,mailinglist_smtp_port);
$mail->setHtml("test");
$mail->setFrom("test@test.nl");    

$mail->setSubject("The ï, ö, ë, ä, and é work, but when adding the ü it doesn't");

$recipients[] = "me@myhost.nl";    
$mail->send($recipients);
```

&

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsMail();
$mail->FromName = 'test';
$mail->From = 'test@test.nl';
$mail->AddAddress("me@myhost.nl");
$mail->Subject = "The ï, ö, ë, ä, and é work, but when adding the ü it doesn't";
$mail->Body = "test";    
$mail->Send();
```

Can anyone help me find the source of and the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should [quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encode the subject header.

Like this:

```
$mail->Subject = "=?UTF-8?Q?" . quoted_printable_encode("The ï, ö, ë, ä, and é work, but when adding the ü it doesn't") . "?=";
```

Quoted printable encode in PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-encode.php

Edit: `$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";` did the job.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't solve it. The subject now turned into: =?UTF-8?Q?The =C3=AF, =C3=B6, =C3=AB, =C3=A4, and =C3=A9 work, but when adding the ==C3=BC it doesn't?=

Comment: Hmm maybe it's enough to add `$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";`, and remove the quoted-printable stuff. Try it and let me know how it works!

Comment: Super, that did the job for the PHPMailer :). Thanks. Now as you can see in my mimemail code, I tried an option similar to this one, but I apparently missed the right setting. Do you perhaps know what I need to set in mimemail to apply the same fix?

Comment: Sweet! I would recommend you to also use PHPMailer to build the MIME message, instead of htmlMimeMail. Else I cannot see what the problem is.

Comment: Another solution is to check out [AlphaMail](http://comfirm.se), which takes care of all this for you :)

Comment: the "Edit" was great!

Comment: In my case utf8_encode($subject) did the job which is basically the same as $mail->CharSet="UTF-8" I guess...