# Bad Header in email subject?

Tags: php, email

I have a rather simple function to send an email.
I started to implement translated versions of the email and with this came special characters such as é and ó. Whenever I have those in the subject of the email, the email creates trouble by causing BAD_HEADER errors in my amavis.

Apparently it is not 8bit encoded, which makes sense at first. However, i can't find anywhere on the net any guide or explanation how to encode the subject properly.

Just for fun I tried é instead of é, and of course the problem was handled. but at the same time the email arrived with é in the subject, instead of é.

Here is the script I have currently:

```
function sendEmail() {

    // Build HTML version
    ob_start();
    include('emailhtml.php');
    $msgHTML = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    // Build TXT version
    ob_start();
    include('email.php');
    $msgTxt = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();


    // Subject & headers
    $subject = "áéíóú";
    $boundary = md5(uniqid(rand())); 
    $headers   = array();
    $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary = ".$boundary;
    $headers[] = "From: ".$from." <".$from_email.">";
    $headers[] = "Reply-To: ".$reply2_email;

    // Plain text version of message
    $body = "--$boundary\r\n" .
       "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n" .
       "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
    $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($msgTxt));

    // HTML version of message
    $body .= "--$boundary\r\n" .
       "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n" .
       "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
    $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($msgHTML));
    $body .= "--$boundary--\r\n";

    // BAM! Shoot it off...
    mail($receiver, $subject, $body, implode("\r\n", $headers));
}
```

Comment: You need to encode the subject, either with quoted printable or base64. Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645869/how-to-set-an-umlaut-u-in-the-mail-subject

Comment: @grebneke thanks, I am trying this solution.

Comment: @grebneke I tried to use this quoted_printable_encode() as given in your link. But my script stops completely when I use this. :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Encoding mail headers**

The `Subject: header` needs to be encoded if it contains any characters outside the `ASCII` character set.

**Encoding type**

There are two encodings you can use: `Quoted Printable` or `Base64`. A typical encoded Subject header for content `áéíóú` looks like this:

```
// Using Quoted Printable encoding:
Subject: =?ISO-8859-1?Q?=C3=A1=C3=A9=C3=AD=C3=B3=C3=BA?=

// Using Base64 encoding:
Subject: =?ISO-8859-1?B?w6HDqcOtw7PDug==?=
```

**The preferred way**

If your `PHP` is compiled with [Multibyte String Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php), you should use [mb_encode_mimeheader()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-encode-mimeheader.php):

```
$subject = "áéíóú";
$encoded_subject = mb_encode_mimeheader($subject);
print $encoded_subject;
// output: =?UTF-8?B?w4PCocODwqnDg8Ktw4PCs8ODwro=?=
```

**The manual way**

If you cannot use `mb_encode_mimeheader()` you could use some [third-party PHP library](https://github.com/ziadoz/awesome-php), or create your own encoding function.

```
$subject = "áéíóú";
$encoded_subject = "=?ISO-8859-1?Q?" . quoted_printable_encode($subject) . "?=";
print $encoded_subject;
// Output: =?ISO-8859-1?Q?=C3=A1=C3=A9=C3=AD=C3=B3=C3=BA?=
```

**The gory details**

Doing MIME-encoding correctly is not trivial. To learn everything about it, you should begin by studying [RFC 2047](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt) and [RFC 2045](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt)

Comment: Thanks, this did the job.  I tried first the quoted printable, but then found out that my provider only runs on php 5.2.17, while quoted printable per documentation was added with 5.3. I use now Base64 and it works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is:  `$Subject = "=?UTF-8?B?". base64_encode($Subject). "?=";`

and this does the reverse:

```
function Subject($subject) {
    $prefix = "=?UTF-8?B?";
    return (stristr($subject,$prefix) === false ? 
                                    $subject : 
        base64_decode(substr(substr($subject,10),0,-2) ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this: `$subject = $subject;`, but you never actually set `$subject`. So, you're passing an uninitialized value to `mail()`, which gets treated as `null` and causes problems.

Answer (score -1):

**$asuntoUFT8** = "Example te desea un Feliz  Cumpleaños !!";

**$asunto** = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($asuntoUFT8)."=?=";

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Comment: A very similar answer already exists in this thread, please explain how yours is different.